# I can't do that loop function

Tags: python, token, turtle-graphics

Here is my project, it' s drawing robot:

I manage to do F and R functions. But my L function always malfunctions.
Here is my code:

```
def func(list1):
numOfElements = int(len(list1))
for i in range(numOfElements):
    if list1[i] == "L":
        list2 = list1.copy()
        for j in range(i):
            list2.pop(j)
        list2.pop(0)
        while(list1[i]!="]"):
            func(list2)
            i=i+1
    if list1[i] == "F":
        value = list1[i + 1]
        tim.forward(value)
    if list1[i] == "R":
        value = list1[i + 1]
        tim.right(value)
    else:
        pass
```

I am using the example in this image. My code separate them into tokens. And then i'm putting them on the list.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I can do this if i had one L function but if there is nested L functions i can't work it out.
How can i solve this problem with my L function?

Comment: I would use recursion to run every `[ ]` in new `func()` - but it would need first parse all data and next maybe it would need `stack` to search matching `[` and `]`. And later it would need to run `F`, `R`

Comment: maybe first you should convert flat list into nested lists, and later run it (using recursion). So don't run `tim.forward` and `tim.right` when you parse it.

Comment: if you would put information as text then it would be simpler to copy it and use in solution. But when information is as image then it is simpler to forget your question and search other questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where you *don't* want a `for i in range(...)` loop as incrementing inside the loop, `i=i+1`, *won't* affect the value of `i` in the next iteration.  Unlike **C**, the Python `for` loop ignores changes to the iteration variable come the next iteration.

Also, copying tokens isn't necessary.  We just need to properly keep track of where we are in the list of tokens.  That includes having a recursive call return how far it got in the list of tokens before it hits a `']'` and returns.

Let's put all that together and use meaningful variable names:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

example = ['L', 36, '[', 'L', 4, '[', 'F', 100, 'R', 90, ']', 'R', 10, ']']

def func(tokens, index=0):
    while index < len(tokens):
        command = tokens[index]
        index += 1

        if command == 'L':
            repetitions = tokens[index]
            index += 2  # also move past '['

            for _ in range(repetitions):
                new_index = func(tokens, index)

            index = new_index
        elif command == 'F':
            distance = tokens[index]
            index += 1
            turtle.forward(distance)
        elif command == 'R':
            angle = tokens[index]
            index += 1
            turtle.right(angle)
        elif command == ']':
            break

    return index

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

func(example)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH. I APPRECIATE TO YOUR HELP. YOU ARE AWESOME, YOU ARE KING, SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH. THANK YOU AGAIN <333